# How to identify a page in apache pdf box

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am reading a document and then splitting it among its pages like below.

```
wholeDocument = PDDocument.load( new File(fileName) );
Splitter splitter = new Splitter();
List<PDDocument> splittedDocuments = splitter.split(wholeDocument);
```

splittedDocuments  would contain the pages. Later, I would be processing these pages one by one.
Is there anyway to uniquely identify a page in this list so that if later my processing fails, I am able to tell this page failed by looking at the actual pdf document.

Comment: what do you mean with "identify" - do you want to know where each new document came from, i.e. what page it had in the past, in the source document?

Comment: @Tilman what page number it had in the whole document

Comment: Should this information be visible (e.g. a footnote), semi-visible (invisible footnote but which can be copied as text), or hidden (to be found only by program access or with PDFDebugger or RUPS)? The first two would involve adding an extra content stream with a text. The last would mean set a private entry in the page dictionary. The last would also be the easiest (one line of code).